# AngularJs "ng-repeat-start" with table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an object in this format, I am trying to print it as a table.

```
[{categoryName: "category1", value:[{name:"item1.1"}{name:"item1.2"},...]}, 
     {categoryName: "category2", value:[{name:"item2.1"},...]},...]
```

So, categaory name should be the header and values under it should be subheaders, as in the colspan of categoryname should be equal to number of values in it.

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr ng-repeat-start="obj in hObj">
                <th ng-repeat="val in obj.value">{{val}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
        </thead>
</table>
```

The above code will print each value of array as different "**tr**".
How can i achieve it?

Edit data: Sorry, data is already flattened i think..

```
[{categoryName: "category1", value:["item1.1","item1.2",...]}, 
{categoryName: "category2", value:["item2.1",...]},...]
```

Comment: Have you considered flattening your data so that you can just iterate over an single, non-nested array that is structured like your desired output?

Comment: Ya, its flattened. I dont know what else i should flatten